# Assemble Peltier Cooler to Li-poly Rc Battery

Tags: power-electronics, power-engineering, peltier, electrical

I have procured a thermoelectric cooler (TEC, [this one](https://sg.element14.com/multicomp/mcpe1-12704ac-s/peltier-cooler-35-2w/dp/1639726)) and my purpose of the TEC is to produce current for the Li-poly RC battery to increase its battery life. The Li-poly RC battery has 7.4V stated on the battery itself.

- Am I supposed to get a DC DC converter?
- And how to go about assembling the TEC to the battery?

Comment: Could you please expand on your theory how do you plan to use the TEC element to prolong the battery life?

Comment: You'll need a battery charge controller, as well as a power source such as the DC-to-DC voltage converter you suggest.

Comment: You'll need an 'energy harvesting' grade DC-DC converter, that is, one that will handle the very low voltage produced by Peltiers (look at Texas Instruments and Analog Devices, both make them) and a charge controller for the cells.

Comment: @Neil_UK thank you!! Will I need a voltage regulator as well?

Comment: You need a LiPo that can supply 61W of power at 15.7V with another 8W CPU cooler fans with same heatsink to achieve 31W of cooling so 1 hr x 15.7 V x 3.9A = 61Wh but 4SxP array @ 4x3.7 only 14.8V down to 4x3V=12V

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 did you actually read the question?

Comment: @EdgarBrown why don’t you correct the terms in the question from Peltier Cooler to Seebeck Effect generator and TEC to TEG.  Maybe  you “can bother” to consider the specs are bidirectional and edit the question.. So if you can create a temp difference of 0’C while applying electrical power  by conductive thermal transfer design and 0’C difference best case. Then   the electrical power input specs becomes thermal power transfer input specs by maximizing the  temperature difference  at the same near 50% best case efficiency transfer is possible and far less if the thermal design is poor.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 why don’t you do it then? You seem to have much more interest in this question than I do.

Comment: Because  you have greater interest in misunderstanding & accuracy

Comment: You ought not to need a voltage regulator if you pick the correct energy harvesting step-up and battery charge controller. Make sure that their output/input voltage ranges overlap, and connect them straight together.

Comment: @Neil_UK alright, thank you for your time. Just to clarify, I should get a step-down DC-DC converter for ultra low power converter?

Comment: No, get a step-up converter to get a sensible voltage out of your Peltier. Use a step-up or step-down charge controller for the cells, whichever you find easiest to source, whose input voltage range overlaps with the output voltage of your first converter.

Comment: @Neil_UK hi may I ask if I should buy an isolated or non-isolated dc/dc converter?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, if it's only connected to peltier and battery, other than cost. If it is connected to other things, then isolated if you need to isolate them, either type if you don't.

Comment: @Neil_UK okay, so is the following connection correct?First, I connect the dc/dc converter to the peltier cooler module, and then connect the battery charge controller to the converter and the lipo battery?

Comment: Yes, sounds alright

Answer (score 0):

You need an MPT converter + LiPo BMS + a thermal delta T power source to harvest the energy in a firm but not over stressed mechanical design.

The temp drop must be maximized while staying within limits to maximize current source with its intrinsic internal ohmic resistance.

In other words, you challenge is get a hot-side heat exchanger, a cold-side heat exchanger, your TEG, a compression assembly system design then an MVPT charger that does impedance matching and tracking for desired output electrical power transfer charger in CC, CV and cutoff modes.

Or in other words buy what you need to match your *yet to be defined* power, thermal energy transfer design, voltage, current specs, impedance for all input AND outputs in each “state” or mode of operation.

## MVPT

e.g. https://thermoelectric-generator.com/product/10w-teg-mvpt-battery-charge-controller/.

Overall it can save fuel, but still a great challenge for Design Engineers. But what you need to learn is beyond the scope of this answer.